# chartjs gradient with angle

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, chart.js

I have been trying different ways to achieve

```
linear-gradient(135deg, #FBCF33 0%, #F53939 90%);
```

in my bar chart. I got close to the required gradient.
However, failed to achieve exactly the same as the one in CSS.

As far as I understand this is due to the angle. How to achieve the same with createLinearGradient

below is what I tried.

```
const angle = 136 * Math.PI / 180;
var x2 = 400 * Math.cos(angle);  // angle in radians
var y2 = 400 * Math.sin(angle);  // angle in radians
var g1 = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, x2, y2);
    g1.addColorStop(0, '#EDDE5D');   
    g1.addColorStop(0.5, '#F09819');
```

Can someone share some thoughts on this?

**EDIT:**

Dataset with color

```
const equipment = [100, 0, 20, 10, 60, 20, 0, 0, 20];
function bgColor(context, c1, c2) {
    const {chart, datasetIndex, index} = context;
    const ds = chart.data.datasets[datasetIndex];
    const value = ds.data[index];
    const y = chart.scales.y.getPixelForValue(value);
    const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(datasetIndex);
    const data = meta.data[index];
    const {x, width, base} = data;
    if (x) {
      const ctx = chart.ctx;
      const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(x, y, x + width, base);
      gradient.addColorStop(0, c1);
      gradient.addColorStop(0.9, c2);
      return gradient;
    }
}

datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Equipment',
            data: equipment,
            backgroundColor(context) {
                return bgColor(context, '#EDDE5D', '#F09819');
            },
            tension: 0.4,
            fill: false,
            borderWidth: 0,
            hoverBorderColor: "#000",
            hoverBackgroundColor: '#FBCF33',
            hoverBorderWidth: 1,
        }]
```

Comment: For future reference, if anyone needs a gradient in a stacked bar chart with chartjs, see the comments of the answer to this ques https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73310580/how-to-give-the-same-gradient-chart-js-type-bar-to-each-datasets/73316563?noredirect=1#comment132991964_73316563

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in identifying the issue as the angle! Your issue here is that the way CSS [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient) interprets "angle".

For CSS:

> The gradient line's angle of direction. A value of 0deg is equivalent to to top; increasing values rotate clockwise from there.

Visualization of the angles:

[image]

When working with Javascript canvas, however, your origin lies with positive x to the right and positive y to the bottom, creating something that looks like this:

[image]

This is causing your gradient to actually be set up in a location off the canvas! Accounting for this, you can match the gradient by setting the same color stops as your CSS code, but adjusting the angle to be 45 degrees. Here's a working example of this:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const angle = 45 * Math.PI / 180;
var x2 = 400 * Math.cos(angle);  // angle in radians
var y2 = 400 * Math.sin(angle);  // angle in radians
var g1 = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, x2, y2);
    g1.addColorStop(0, '#FBCF33');   
    g1.addColorStop(0.9, '#F53939');
    ctx.fillStyle = g1;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
```

```css
div{
   width:400px;
   height:400px; 
   background: linear-gradient(135deg, #FBCF33 0%, #F53939 90%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice answer, but there's just a small error in how you compute the starting and ending points of the canvas gradient. The colors in the top-right and bottom-left corners are visibly (and measurably) different in your code snippet. For the colors to match those of css, in this particular case (greatly simplified by the fact that the angle is 45deg) the starting point is (0,0) (right) and the end point is (400, 400) (that is no cos/sin). For a general angle value, the formula is more complicated - see the image [from MDN](shorturl.at/jktFR) or even the one [from the css](shorturl.at/dhTY2)

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I tried following this. However, I noticed that the gradient is being applied to complete canvas, I need gradient for individual bar in the chart

Comment: Could you give more context for your code? I don't understand how the gradient applies to your bar chart. Part of matching the CSS gradient is ensuring they have the same size.

Comment: Ok, I edited and added the code, I also managed to add the gradient to the individual bar of the chart, I will apply your suggestion now and see if that works.